# Como fazer linhas se cruzando em uma borda, com CSS?

Tags: css

alguém sabe como fazer uma borda que "vaza" pra fora da div assim como na imagem?

preciso dessa borda cruzada dos cantos inferiores , esses "xiszinhos" ou "cruzinhas"

Obrigado desde já

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Segue uma solução que usa uma `div` para fazer a borda cruzada, usando pseudo-elementos:

```css
.borda {
  display:inline-block; position:relative;
}

.borda:before {
  content:''; display:block; position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  left:4px; right:4px;         /* tamanho horizontal do cruzamento */
  border-left:1px solid #999;
  border-right:1px solid #999;
}

.borda:after {
  content:''; display:block; position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:4px;                  /* tamanho vertical do cruzamento */
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}

img {
  margin:0 25px 25px 25px;     /* tamanho do espaço em branco */ 
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px #999; /* sombra da imagem            */
}
```

```html
<div class="borda"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpq5z.png"></div>
```

Se tudo o que precisa é a borda com espaço, fica mais simples:

```css
.borda {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 25px 25px 25px;    /* zero de espaço em cima, 25px no resto */
  border:1px solid #999;       /* borda em toda a volta */
  border-top:none;             /* menos em cima         */
}

img {
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px #999; /* sombra da imagem      */
}
```

```html
<div class="borda"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpq5z.png"></div>
```

Comment: percebi que o .borda:before  ele bloquei o clique de qualquer coisa dentro da div. Tenho umas tags <a> dentro da div que ficam bloqueadas como se estivesse algo em cima, quando retiro o .borda:before  ele funciona.
Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema do click.
coloquei meus links dentro de uma div com posição relativa.
Obrigado pessoal

Comment: @AlexMartins você pode colocar pointer-events:none no before e after, aí eles ficam transparentes pro click. é que normalmente eu imaginei que o click ia ser na div toda, e nao só na imagem, então nem coloquei. Eu acho que pro usuário é melhor sua solução de colocar a ancora fora da borda, ai fica mais acessivel.

Answer (score 3):

Coloque dentro de outra `div` que possua `padding` e a tal `border`.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.a {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.b {
    background: #F00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Ou então, veja aqui:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVLoYq

Comment: Acho que ele ta falando daquele 'cruzadinho' nos cantos da borda.

Comment: Pois @Bruno. Se realmente é, não dá para perceber pela pergunta.

Comment: É verdade, a pergunta tá muito incompleta.

Comment: Pessoal desculpe se não me fiz entender por completo , mas é isso mesmo, preciso dessa borda cruzada dos cantos inferiores , esses "xiszinhos"